# Terraform for loop key value output

Tags: terraform

I was recently for work on for and for_each loops with terrform. From the documentation and every where to loop through the maps and for using the values we use syntax

`value = {for k,v in {some_variable} : k => v }`

just wanted to understand more on k=> v value what it is doing i know it will output the map but i want to understand more on => job in this expression

Comment: It just TF syntax. Not sure what exactly is unclear?

Comment: Hey @Marcin, I do understand whatever you are saying.. lt do has some name like in java the same syntax has a name called lambda operator .. what does its called in HCL or Terraform code.?

Comment: It just builds a map on the for loop output.

Comment: In TF these are called [for Expressions](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for).

Answer (score 1):

When you use the expression k => v, you are essentially creating a new map element with k as the key and v as the value. This syntax allows you to transform the original map into a new map with potentially different keys and values.